# Jira Swimlanes Query - Blocked Issues are to be displayed together

Tags: jira, project-management, agile, jql

Could someone please help with creating a JQL Query for the Swimlwne of our board to display issues that are blocked (by bugs for e.g) near with this bugs actually?
I also need to display such tickets only of the blocking issue is not closed (if possible).

Thanks in advance.

`project = 123 AND issuetype = Story AND issueLinkType = "is blocked by" OR issueLinkType = blocks`

but it actually added all unclosed stories here even if the issue which is blocking it has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Showing issues and their blocked issues near each other on board is not possible (it's possible to display them on a single board but not next to each other).

You don't mention if it's Jira Cloud or on-prem (Server or DC).

For DC, I would suggest focusing on creating a [custom scripted field](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/script-fields) (or issue picker field) by ScriptRunner or using [Issue Matrix](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212709/issue-matrix-for-jira?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview) fields to display blocked issues right on the Bug issue itself. This way it would be display right on the issue (in Issue View) and also on boards (which is what you need). [vLinks](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219910/vlinks-easy-issue-linking?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview) add-on might also help.